# How to bind a component to the backend document instead of the bean when in Read mode?

Tags: xpages

If a component is bound to a bean the value of the actual field from backend document is not retrieved when in Read mode.

How do I bind the component to the backend document instead of the bean when in Read mode?

Comment: You should use your bean for both readmode and editmode. So you need to make sure that your bean reads the correct values when initialized, that it saves the correct values etc.

Comment: OK, thanx Per. This is not what I thought I had to do. Too much impact just to have a bean to calculate some values. Lesson learned! ;)